# (Vue/Nuxt, async await, promise) When trigger beforeRouteLeave, use Promise to ask child component and wait for the return answer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, nuxt.js

The full demo environment on: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-raman-ynxs3?file=/pages/question.vue)

The question is I need to define a custom dialog for confirmation when the user leaves the page.

The demo showed two pages, which are `index` and `question`. Only `question` page will have `beforeRouteLeave` challenge. `beforeRouteLeave` is an `async` function to trigger custom dialog open and `await` the result that if `true`, let the user leave.

**page/index.vue**

`no special rules`

**page/question.vue**

```
<template>
  ...
  <nuxt-link to="/">Go to home</nuxt-link>

  <leaveWarning v-if="leaveLightbox" @returnApproval="leaveWindowReturn"/>
  <!-- @returnApproval is the child component emitted the result that user click yes or no to leave -->
  ...
</template>

<script>
import leaveWarning from "~/components/leaveWarning.vue"
export default{
  components: {
    leaveWarning,
    ...
  },
  data: () => ({
    leaveLightbox: false
  }),
  async beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    let approval = await this.launchLeaveWindow();
    this.$set(this, "leaveLightbox", false);
    if (approval) {
      next();
    } else {
      next(false);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    launchLeaveWindow() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.$set(this, "leaveLightbox", true);
        resolve(this.leaveWindowReturn());
      });
    },
    leaveWindowReturn(payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("payload: " + payload);
        if (payload) {
          resolve(true);
        } else if (payload === false) {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

**components/leaveWarning.vue**

Will return `$emit("returnApproval", boolean)`

```
<template>
  <section class="lightbox" @click.self="closeLeaveWindow">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Leave Now?</h2>
      <p>Are you sure to leave? The data will lose when leave now.</p>
      <div>
        <div class="button" @click="approveLeave">Yes</div>
        <div class="button" @click="closeLeaveWindow">No</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({}),
  methods: {
    closeLeaveWindow() {
      console.log("clicked: no")
      this.$emit("returnApproval", false);
    },
    approveLeave() {
      console.log("clicked: yes")
      this.$emit("returnApproval", true);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The issue is the method `launchLeaveWindow` called by `beforeRouteLeave`, cannot wait for `leaveWindowReturn` with return boolean. That's mean the promise cannot keep waiting for the child component to emit the result.

I hope when triggered `beforeRouteLeave`, then trigger `launchLeaveWindow`, and wait for the result when trigger `leaveWindowReturn`. And finally, use the return from `leaveWindowReturn` pass to `beforeRouteLeave` to verify the redirect challenge.

Any idea to solve the problem? Sorry, I am new to use Promise.